# Drag&Drop Failure with Scatterview Items and Grid Layout

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, multi-touch, pixelsense

[Link to the Image of my App](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/84520)

I want to detect if the 2 Pictures on canvas are neary each other, an than make some compare operation with the data that is embedded in the pictures if both are touched an near each other.

The brown Area is a ScatterView where i can drop picture elements an add them to the green listbox.

I can drop picture items directly from the blue list box to the brown drop area.

But when i drop them first on the yellow scatterview, then i can't get out of there to drop them on the brown scatterview.

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
<Grid.RowDefinitions >
  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <s:ScatterView 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
        Grid.RowSpan="1" 
        x:Name="ScatterLayer" 
        Background="Yellow" 
        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ScatterItemStyle}" 
        AllowDrop="True"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageAndCaptionTemplate}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ScatterItems}" 
        s:SurfaceDragDrop.Drop="ScatterLayer_Drop" 
        s:SurfaceDragDrop.DragEnter="ScatterLayer_DragEnter" 
        s:SurfaceDragDrop.DragCompleted="ScatterLayer_DragCompleted" >
    </s:ScatterView>

    <s:SurfaceListBox 
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
        AllowDrop="True"
        x:Name="ListBoxVerticalBasket"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Background="GreenYellow"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BasketItems}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BasketTemplate}" >
        <s:SurfaceListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </s:SurfaceListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </s:SurfaceListBox>

    <s:SurfaceListBox 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
        x:Name="ShoppingList"
        AllowDrop="True" 
        s:SurfaceDragDrop.DragCompleted="OnShoppingListDragCompleted" 
        s:SurfaceDragDrop.DragCanceled="OnShoppingListDragCanceled" 
        PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnShoppingListPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
        PreviewMouseMove="OnShoppingListPreviewMouseMove" 
        PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="OnShoppingListPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LibraryItems}" 
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageAndCaptionTemplate}"
        PreviewTouchDown="OnShoppingListPreviewTouchDown" 
        PreviewTouchMove="OnShoppingListPreviewTouchMove" 
        PreviewTouchUp="OnShoppingListPreviewTouchUp" 
        Background="#FF00BDD8">
        <s:SurfaceListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" AllowDrop="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </s:SurfaceListBox.ItemsPanel>

    </s:SurfaceListBox>

    <s:ScatterView 
        Grid.Column="2" 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Background="DarkGoldenrod" 
        Width="300" 
        Height="100"
        x:Name="ScatterViewDropArea"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        AllowDrop="True"
        s:SurfaceDragDrop.Drop="ScatterViewDropArea_Drop">
    </s:ScatterView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using the `DragDropScatterView` that comes with the Shopping Cart demo in the Surface SDK instead of `ScatterView`.